# runtime is super long

Tags: python, function, numpy, runtime

I have the following code:

```
m1 = sig*np.random.randn(N)+mu
m2 = sig*np.random.randn(N)+mu
dl = np.random.uniform(low=0,high=600*Mp,size=N)
Mchirp = (m1+m2)*(m1*m2/(m1+m2)**2)**(3/5)


def SNR2(Mchirp,dl):
    A = -(Mp/dl)*2*np.sqrt(5/(24*np.pi))*(G*Ms/(c**2*dl*Mp))*(G*np.pi*Ms/(c**3))**(-1/6)*(Mchirp/Ms)**(-5/6)
    return A**2*integrate.quad(lambda f: f**(-2.3333)/S(f), 20, 1500, limit=1000)[0]

trigs = np.empty(N)

print trigs.shape

def trig_decision(SNR2):
    for i in range(len(SNR2(Mchirp,dl))):
        if SNR2(Mchirp,dl)[i] > SNRth:
            trigs[i] = 1
        else:
            trigs[i] = 0
    return trigs

trig_decision(SNR2)
```

I just want it to take a list of 52500 values from my function SNR2 and check if they're greater than a given threshold. When I just run SNR2(Mchirp,dl) it takes about 3 seconds to run. But when I run my trig_decision function, it takes forever. Is there a reason why this is happening, and a way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time around the loop, you’re running `SNR2()` again. Don’t do that! It’s better style to use `enumerate` anyways:

```
def trig_decision(SNR2):
    for i, x in enumerate(SNR2(Mchirp, dl)):
        if x > SNRth:
            trigs[i] = 1
        else:
            trigs[i] = 0
    return trigs
```

It doesn’t really seem like there should be a global there, either:

```
def trig_decision(SNR2):
    return [int(x > SNRth) for x in SNR2(Mchirp, dl)]

trigs = trig_decision(SNR2)
```